# Print menus with dropdowns from 1 list from Database

Tags: php, database, dropdown

I have the following on database:

Table: menu

|  | name | slug | order | submenu | fk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | menu 1 | m001 | 1 | 0 | null |
| 2 | menu 2 | m002 | 2 | 0 | null |
| 3 | menu 3 | m003 | 3 | 1 | null |
| 4 | sub3.1 | s001 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 5 | sub3.2 | s002 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 6 | sub3.3 | s002 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 7 | menu 4 | m004 | 4 | 1 | null |
| 8 | sub4.1 | s003 | 4 | 0 | 7 |
| 9 | sub4.2 | s004 | 4 | 0 | 7 |

I have to do this (yes 1 select from db):

```
$list = Sql->select('SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY order, submenu DESC, name');
```

i get the list correctly :)

I need this:

```html
<UL>
  <li><a ...> menu 1 </a></li>
  <li><a ...> menu 2 </a></li>
  <li><a ...> menu 3 </a>
      <div>
         <a ...> sub3.1 </a>
         <a ...> sub3.2 </a>
         <a ...> sub3.3 </a>
      </div>
  </li>
  <li><a ...> menu 4 </a>
      <div>
         <a ...> sub4.1 </a>
         <a ...> sub4.2 </a>
      </div>
  </li>
</UL>
```

I´m doing this:

```
<UL><?php
  $is_prev_subitem = false;

  foreach($list as $menu){
   $is_submenu = $menu['submenu']==1;
   $is_subitem = $menu['fk']>0;
   
   if($is_prev_subitem && !$is_subitem){ echo "</div></li>"; }

   if(!$is_subitem){
     echo "<LI class='nav-item ".($is_submenu ? ' dropdown' : '')."'>";
   }

   echo "<a href='#' class='nav-link ".($is_submenu ? ' dropdown-toggle' : '')."' id='{$menu['slug']}'> {$menu['name']} </a>";
   if($is_submenu){
     echo "<div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='{$menu['slug']}'>";
   }


   if(!$is_subitem){
     echo "</LI>";
   }

   $is_prev_subitem = $is_subitem;
  }
?>
</UL>
```

But the A elements be outside div.dropdown-menu. What can be ? Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved changing last ***if*** sentence, doing this:

```
if(!$is_subitem && !$is_submenu){
   echo "</LI>";
}
```